# How to run django-allauth flows inside an iframe and close it at the end of flow?

Tags: python, django, iframe, redirect, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth (version 0.21.0, django 1.8, python 3.4).

The problems I have concerning the fact that my allauth flows/screens are shown inside an iframe (that's what the designer decided :)).

[allauth iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itIr2.png)

I have 2 problems that connected to each other:

1.
When a user completes login/signup successfully, the redirect url that pass through the response is the landing page (localhost:8080), and that is what shown on the iframe.

[landing page inside iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXcj0.png)

I want to refresh the iframe's parent window on that case.
In order to do that, I edited utils.py 
(my_virtual_env\Lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py).

On perform_login function:

```
def perform_login(request, user, email_verification,
                  redirect_url=None, signal_kwargs=None,
                  signup=False):
[…]
    try:
        get_adapter().login(request, user)
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(get_login_redirect_url(request, redirect_url))
[…]
    return response
```

I replaced

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(get_login_redirect_url(request, redirect_url))
```

with

```
response = HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">parent.refreshLanding();</script>')
```

That action did refreshed the main window (landing page) and closed the iframe after success login, but caused other side effects because now other processes that dependent on the redirect url (I guess) are not occurs:
A. redirect to land page after user confirms his email address
B. problem 2

2.
Login to social accounts cannot perform inside an iframe (due to clickjacking attacks).
Facebook took responsibility of that (opening a popup by default and close it automatically at the end of the login/signup).
I manually opened a new popup window on google and twitter signup and login processes.

I used a JavaScript setInterval() to close the popup and refresh the landing page if the popup's url equals to the landing page.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (popupWindow.location.href.indexOf("http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/") === 0) {
        popupWindow.close();
        window.parent.location = window.parent.location;
    }
}, 1);
```

But since I changed HttpResponseRedirect to HttpResponse (on utils.py), the popup url doesn't change after success sign up, and I dont have indication when to close the popup window.

I really hope that you will have a decent way of handling that situation.